# Configure Nginx to use several directories

Tags: html, ubuntu, nginx, config

There config nginx that when referring to http://example.com/sellers
must give the server from folder /data/sellers
In another case - of folder /data/customers

Nginx config:

```
    server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    index index.html index.htm home.html;

    location /sellers {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        rewrite ^/sellers/?(.*) /$1 break;
        root   /data/sellers;
    }

    location / {
        root   /data/customers;
    }
}
```

Everything works, but is not entirely correct: when accessing the server sellers somehow uses index.html from folder /data/customers/index.html
And all the rest of the folder /data/sellers (this is correct)
What can be wrong? Why nginx takes the wrong index.html file, even though all the rest of Georgia right?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not in English.

Comment: Вам в http://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Sorry. I will translate now

Comment: I think that writing in the Russian community. Sorry again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  localhost;
  index index.html index.htm home.html;
  root /data/customers;

  location /sellers {
    alias /data/sellers;
  }
}
```